# EOS Programming tools in the near future?

Tags: dapp, development

I am starting to make my first steps on EOS programming but I find the tools available to be quite raw at the time being. There are many things (Integrated IDEs, platform installers, etc) that could be a huge help in the development process. [In this article](https://steemit.com/eos/@timotteo/eos-programming-tools-we-must-build-to-attract-a-broader-range-of-developers) many of those possible features are described. Not sure if this is the right place to look for suchs efforts, but, are there any efforts being done at all to build such tools? I would love to join those

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio,

If you would like to chip in, I would recommend helping out with  GenerEOS's toolkit **([Site](https://eostoolkit.io/home))([Github](https://github.com/generEOS))** or EOS New York's Resource Planner **([Site](https://www.eosrp.io/))([Github](https://github.com/eosnewyork/erp))**

[I also made a steemit post on the developer tools currently out there.](https://steemit.com/eos/@natp/ultimate-eos-developer-link-guide)

Answer (score 1):

The amazing potential of EOS will attract a lot of developers. The more dapp developers in the EOS ecosystem, the more development support tools will be available. Now is a bit uncomfortable for a while.

I am developing a EOS design support and implementation automation tool.The tool analyzes contracts, supports designs based on them, and automates the implementation.

I have developed UML-based design support and implementation automation tools(See the figure below), and based on this I have been developing EOS tools.

[image]

Numerous developers entering the EOS ecosystem will develop and share the tools they need. The EOS community should support these tool developers as well.

You would love to join those.